# .htacces redirection issue with subfolder php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect this link http://www.usedcarstampa.com/blog/?m=201511
to 
http://www.usedcarstampa.com/blog/

I am trying the following  in .htaccess file

1) Not working

```
Redirect /usedcarstampa.com/blog/index.php?m=201511  /index.php
```

2) Not working

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=201511(&|$) [NC]
Rewrite-rule ^index.php$ /? [R=301,NC] // not working
```

note :- main site in core PHP and blog part in word-press 
there is also a another ht-access file in blog/ directory. I am also try above code to right there but i not get positive result

please help,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule as **very first rule** in your `/blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=201511(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Rule is correct as it works on my Apache in `/blog/` directory. You have to make sure that `/blog/.htaccess` is working and this is first rule.

Comment: yes sir , your code is correct but still i am not get redirection actually i fix 300 error in ht-access only this one not get fix  there is some other issue occurs ?

Comment: Can you show your latest `/blog/.htaccess` in question?